# My .click method only works sometimes then gives an error other times

Tags: html, ruby, capybara

I am using Capybara to scrape a site and one of the actions is clicking a button. Sometimes Capybara clicks it and other times is gives this error

```
/Users/maximushan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/poltergeist-1.18.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/node.rb:25:in `rescue in command': Firing a click at co-ordinates [632.5, 546.5] failed. Poltergeist detected another element with CSS selector 'html body.ab_test_B.not_sem.not_from_partner.not_mobile.is_desktop.f-topbar-fixed.lazy-load div.autocomplete-suggestions div.autocomplete-suggestion' at this position. It may be overlapping the element you are trying to interact with. If you don't care about overlapping elements, try using node.trigger('click'). (Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed)
```

The two click methods that I have tried are

```
.find(:button, 'js-emu-submit').click
.click_on 'js-emu-submit'
```

I am not really sure why they work sometimes but break other times.

Comment: Have you tried to follow this instruction `If you don't care about overlapping elements, try using node.trigger('click')`? It seems, that your button may be overlapped by some kind of popup from time to time, which is common on modern websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're getting is pretty self-explanatory, another element is over the element you're trying to click on.  From the selector shown of the other element `'html body.ab_test_B.not_sem.not_from_partner.not_mobile.is_desktop.f-topbar-fixed.lazy-load div.autocomplete-suggestions div.autocomplete-suggestion'` we can assume it's a suggestion in an autocomplete box you're filling info into. That means there are a couple of possibilities

1. This is a box that will go away if given enough time and then leave the element you're trying to click clickable. In that case check for the box to go away

   ```
   expect(page).not_to have_css('div.autocomplete-suggestion') # RSpec
   # page.assert_no_css('div.autocomplete-suggestion') # minitest
   page.click_button('js_emu_submit')
   ```
2. You're filling in data in the autosuggest box that presents multiple matching options, in which case the dropdown isn't going to go away. In that case you need to do whatever a user would do in this case (maybe click on a matching autocomplete suggestion) like

   ```
   page.find('div.autocomplete-suggestion', exact_text: 'whatever you want to select').click
   expect(page).not_to have_css('div.autocomplete-suggestion')
   page.click_button('js_emu_submit')
   ```

If you're using a recent version of Capybara then it's more likely to be number 2 because recent versions will attempt re-clicking when clicks are blocked. For older versions of Capybara it could be either.